# Javascript parseInt doesn't work as expectedd

Tags: javascript

I'm working with javascript, but something doesn't work as I expected. It is a line of code like:

```
const val = parseInt(100/1000000000, 10);
```

I expect that the result is 0, but javascript's result is 1. But why?
Then I try something like:

```
parseInt(0.000001, 10) // returns 0
parseInt(0.0000001, 10) // returns 1, I expect to have 0
```

How do I get my expected result with this kind of code?

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt` [coerces the first argument to a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if it's not a string already.

Somewhat small values like `0.0001` get coerced to `'0.0001'`.

But quite small values like `0.0000001` get coerced to `'1e-7'`. That should make the problem pretty obvious: only the leading numeric digits get parsed by `parseInt`.

Only try to `parseInt` on *strings*. If you have a number, use a different method, like `Math.round` or `Math.ceil`.

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` is for *parsing* integers, out of strings. It converts its argument to a string. In your first case, `"1e-7"` is converted to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt:

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer

You are looking for `Math.round`.

Answer (score 0):

As Meagar noted, `parseInt` converts strings to (integer) numbers.  If you give it something that isn't a string, like a boolean or a number, you're going to get weird results, because you're misusing the tool.

A simple fix would be to convert your number to a string first, and then you would get the expected result.  For instance ...

```
  parseInt('0.0000001', 10);
  // 0
```